# apple app Integrating credit card payments

Tags: ios, payment, credit-card

It's my first ios app and I would like to sell some products through my app. In my app, users should pay with their credit cards after buying products. So, I want to integrate credit card payments api in my app and I may use Strip (any other recommendation?).
My question is: Would apple allow me to do this in my app? If not,what should I do to let apple allow me? I haven't upload app before, and would like to register a developer account when my app get finished. So, need seniors' help.

Comment: In app purchases via apples own system is the way to go. Having your own method will result in rejection from review.

Comment: That is only for digital content. You can use credit card for tangible products.

Comment: It depends on the type of thing you are selling.  Digital goods that are designed for use inside the app are **required** to use Apple's in app purchase API.  Other goods (physical goods / goods for use outside of the app) are **required NOT** to use Apple's in app purchase API.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Yes, Apple will allow this as long as the products are not digital for use in the app.

> Real-world goods and services. You must deliver a digital good or service within your app when using In-App Purchase. Use a different payment mechanism to let your users buy real-world goods and services in your app, such as a credit card or payment service.

[Source](https://developer.apple.com/library/ios/documentation/NetworkingInternet/Conceptual/StoreKitGuide/Chapters/Products.html)

Answer (score 0):

Yeah Apple will let you.

I honestly prefer Paypal. It takes care of everything.

https://github.com/paypal/PayPal-iOS-SDK